# Geocoder - how to fetch the country/region name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geolocation, rails-geocoder

I am trying to obtain the city, country and region name with using the [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) gem.
This is how I am doing it:

```
geo_data = Geocoder.search('50.131.44.XXX')
puts geo_data.inspect
puts geo_data[0].city
#puts geo_data[0].inspect
puts geo_data[0].country_code
puts geo_data[0].region_name
```

and the output:

```
[#<Geocoder::Result::Freegeoip:0x007fd6db981b38 @data={"ip"=>"50.131.44.XXX", "country_code"=>"US", "country_name"=>"United States", "region_code"=>"CA", "region_name"=>"California", "city"=>"Sunnyvale", "zipcode"=>"94087", "latitude"=>XXX, "longitude"=>-XXX, "metro_code"=>"807", "areacode"=>"408"}, @cache_hit=nil>]
Sunnyvale
US
NoMethodError (undefined method `region_name' for #<Geocoder::Result::Freegeoip:0x007fd6db981b38>):
```

Why I cannot get the region name?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`geo_data[0].data["region_name"]`.Accessing a value in a [Hash#[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html#method-i-5B-5D) requires using its key

`Geocoder.search()` method return `array` with object `data`. In data you have simple `hash` with value.

Comment: (undefined method `[]' for #<Geocoder::Result::Freegeoip:0x00000004735f88

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27519219/geocoder-not-working-properly-with-rails-4