# Searching location by IP using Geocoder gem not working properly with rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-geocoder

I have added `geocoder` gem in my rails application but it is not responding properly when i am searching location by IP.

The problem is that it's returning nil array.

```
Geocoding API's response was not valid JSON.
[]
```

But sometimes it's working, I don't know why.

**What I have done:**

*Gemfile*

```
gem 'geocoder'
```

*initializers/geocoder.rb*

```
Geocoder.configure(
    :timeout  => 20,
    :lookup   => :google,
    #:ip_lookup => :google,
    #:api_key  => "xxxx-xxx",
    :units    => :km
)
```

*application_controller.rb*

```
def current_location
 if Rails.env.development?
  geo_data = Geocoder.search('50.131.44.114')
 else
  geo_data = Geocoder.search(request.remote_ip)
 end
 [geo_data[0].city, geo_data[0].country_code ].compact.join(', ') 
end
```

Comment: I have also tried with different timeouts 15,20,30

Comment: having the same issue with trying to get my ip_address to geocode. i'm going to open an issue tomorrow if I can't find any answers

Answer (score 0):

was getting the same error 
used this
" Geocoder.configure(ip_lookup: :telize) " it solved the problem.
source - https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder/issues/770

Comment: Please specify a valid lookup for Geocoder (:telize is not one of: :dstk, :esri, :google, :google_premier, :yahoo, :bing, :geocoder_ca, :geocoder_us, :yandex, :nominatim, :mapquest, :ovi, :baidu, :test, :freegeoip, :maxmind).

Comment: :ip_lookup, not :lookup

Comment: Yes i was able to solve that issue but still Geocoder not working properly.